# Properties of the Zariski topology on Proj

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, projective-schemes, zariski-topology

Let $S_\bullet$ be a $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})$-graded ring, $f \in S_+$ be a homogenous element, $I \subseteq S_+$ any homogenous ideal, $V_+(I) := \{p \in ProjS_\bullet | I \subseteq p \}$.

I'm working through the text from Ravi Vakil on algebraic geometry and there is the following exercise:

> Show that $V_+(I) \subseteq V_+(f)$ iff. $f \in \sqrt{I}$.

There is a hint stating, that one should "mimic" the proof of this statement for the affine case.

In the case of $Spec$ I just showed that $\sqrt I = \cap_{p \in V(I)}{p}$ - and it seems to me that this is the way Vakil had in mind, as in a hint for the affine case of the statement he referred to an earlier exercise showing $\sqrt I = \cap_{p\in V(I)}{p}$.
Therefore I tried to prove $\sqrt I = \cap_{p \in V_+(I)}{p}$ but I'm only able to show '$\subseteq$' and I feel like '$\supseteq$' may be wrong in general.

So here is my question:

> Is it true that $\sqrt I = \cap_{p \in V_+(I)}{p}$, if so - why is that. If it is not true, what do you think is the "intended" proof one should mimic?

I think I found a solution to the problem, but it is not really a mimic of my proof for $Spec$ and I'd really like to see that.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq I$. If $\mathfrak{p} \in V_+(I)$, then of course $f \in \mathfrak{p}$. If not, then $S_+ \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ and hence $f \in \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Ahh alright, this shows "$\Rightarrow$". Very cool, thanks :-)